# Prohibited variable names

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Is it somehow possible to call a C# variable `return`?

I need to deserialize JSON data and there is a field called `return`.

And I am unable to create class with this name to create object for deserialization :-/

Thank you.

Comment: Return (capital first char)

Comment: @return - The @ symbol lets you use reserved names for variables and classes

Answer (score 4):

Either use `@return` or simply annotate it ([JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)):

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "return")]
public string MyPropertyName {get; set;}
```

Comment: Yes, do this! Please don't name your C# variable/property `@return`, it's confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use keywords as identifiers by prefixing them with `@`:

```
public int Foo()
{
    int @return = 5;
    return @return;
}
```

Note that this is not necessary for the so-called *contextual* keywords, such as LINQ operators, `var` and others that came later. Those have special rules where they can appear which allow them to be used as identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Try prefixing the variable name with '@'.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx